# Meaning of "crutch 'gin" in Browning's Childe Roland

Tags: phrase-meaning, abbreviations, poetry, elizabethan-english

From Browning's [Childe Roland](http://www.bartleby.com/246/654.html):

> What else should he be set for, with his staff?
>     What, save to waylay with his lies, ensnare
>     All travellers who might find him posted there,
>   And ask the road? I guess’d what skull-like laugh
>   Would break, what **crutch ’gin** write my epitaph
>     For pastime in the dusty thoroughfare

What is the meaning of "crutch 'gin"? I know the meaning of crutch, but what does **'gin** mean here? "Going"? "Again"? These do not seem to fit.

Comment: "What crutch [would] **begin** [to] write my epitaph" -- the narrator imagines the "hoary cripple" writing his epitaph in the dusty road with his crutch.

Comment: @StoneyB - thank you, I would never have guessed! Case closed.

Comment: @StoneyB - it's a pity he did not come up with a clearer wording. Would any native speaker understand this 'gin right away?

Comment: *'gin* is a common abbreviation in Elizabethan English; Browning was immersed in the Elizabethan stage, and could count on his readers to recognize it. The ellipses are pretty ordinary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What crutch [would] **begin** [to] write my epitaph" -- the narrator imagines the "hoary cripple" writing his epitaph in the dusty road with his crutch.

**'gin** is a common abbreviation in Elizabethan English; Browning was immersed in the Elizabethan stage, and could count on his readers to recognize it. The ellipses are pretty ordinary.

(Kudos to [StoneyB](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/32/stoneyb))